# nested custom controls in windows8.1 xaml

Tags: c#-4.0, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I need to create some custom controls in windows8.1 and also add some validation to it.
I would like keep this validations as separate part and apply that to each the custom control.
Is it possible to do this.Can any suggest a way to achieve this.

Thanking you,
CGN

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need a bit more information than that. Do you mean you want to create a form, like a textbox, with input validation, such as making sure it has a minimum length? What do you mean "keep it as a separate part and apply that to each custom control"? Do you mean that you want to be able to trigger that functionality on one control, but not another?

Comment: I need to display a validation text and another notification text in each custom control.
In a normal way i can include this all in the custom control inside the generic.xaml.My question:: is it possible to separate that code in a common place and refer inside each custom control. Or can i inherit and use the code in the generic.xaml.

Comment: You can do either. Storing the style/template inside of Generic.xaml is called a 'Templated Control'. Storing it inside of its own `.xaml` file is called a `UserControl`. If you create a new item in your project and tell it to create a `UserControl`, it will make a whole file your you, similar to a new `Page`.

Comment: I'm talking about Templated control. I've already created them and successfully running in the app.but as part of code review i need to separate the validation control in common place.It will be great if i can do that way..

Comment: Well, you could add them to their own .xaml files and then include that .xaml in your App.xaml's `Resources` `MergedDictionaries`.